# most elegant technique for comparing content of bash array with a content of a file

Tags: bash

I would like to compare a content of an array with a content of a file. I guess the best solution is to:

```
b=( some data )
a=$(<file)
if [ $a -ne ${b[@]} ]
then
    echo "variables are different"
fi
```

Am I correct?

Comment: You need to define what the expected representation of the array is. Do you intend the items to be space separated, line-break separated, quoted, or what?

Comment: @ams : word-spliting will rearrange the stuff

Comment: Note that `-ne` is Bourne shell *arithmetic*, not text, comparison, is that what you are looking for?   Is the file multi-line?

Comment: In addition to what cdarke said, if `b` contains more than one element the `if` would fail with the error "too many arguments"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$ cat file
a
b
c
$ echo -n "arrays are "
$ x1=( a b c )
$ mapfile -t x2 < file
$ [[ ${x1[@]} == ${x2[@]} ]] && echo "identical" || echo >&2 "different"
```

Comment: You can use `mapfile -t x2 < file` instead of `x2=( $(<file) )`, it's MUCH more efficient! and that's exactly what `mapfile` is for! `mapfile` can actually do much more

Comment: I don't have mapfile, and my Archlinux don't know how to download it

Comment: It's a `bash` builtin! `help mapfile`

Answer (score -1):

By using Bash's process substitution:

```
b=( some data )
if ! diff <(echo ${b[*]}) file; then
  echo "different"
fi
```